# Value from jquery populated field, not saving to model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP MVC app.  I have a select list which is populated from the viewmodel (Task Name).  Based off the selected item, a decimal value is placed in the textbox for TaskValue.  The jquery side is working, the value shows up in the field, but when submitted, the TaskValue field is null.  How can I get the value to submit?

ViewModel:

```
namespace MyJobs.Models
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public CompletedTask CompTaskModel { get; set; }
        public TaskList TaskListModel { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Tasks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CompletedTasks Model:

```
namespace MyJobs.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(CompTaskData))]
    public partial class CompletedTask
    {
    }

    public class CompTaskData
    {
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        public decimal TaskValue { get; set; }
        public DateTime CompDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TaskList Model

```
namespace MyJobs.Models
{
    [MetadataType (typeof(TaskListData))]
    public partial class TaskList
    {
    }

    public class TaskListData
    {
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        public decimal TaskValue { get; set; }

    }
}
```

the view:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompTaskModel.TaskName, new SelectList(Model.Tasks, "Value", "Text"), "Select a Job")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompTaskModel.TaskName)
    </div>
```

the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CompTaskModel_TaskName").change(function () {
        var v = 0;
//        var value = $("#CompTaskModel_TaskValue").val();
        var task = $("#CompTaskModel_TaskName").val();

        switch (task) {
            case "1":
                v = "$0.50";
            break;
            case "2":
                v = "$0.75";
            break;
            case "3":
                v = "$0.50";
            break;
            case "4":
                v = "$0.75";
                break;
            default:
                v = "Select a Job!";
            }

           $("#CompTaskModel_TaskValue").val(v);
     });
   });
```

the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();

        vm.Tasks = from e in db.TaskList.ToArray()
                   select new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Value = e.TaskId.ToString(),
                       Text = e.TaskName
                   };

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Thank you for your assistance.

EDIT:  I am also getting an error, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the dropdownfor line of the view:

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompTaskModel.TaskName, new SelectList(Model.Tasks, "Value", "Text"), "Select a Job")
```

Comment: You should first distinguish if the problem is in MVC or jQuery. You said that jQuery is working so why are you giving additional noise to your question. It would be lot easier to help you if you provide us with information most related to the problem. I would like to see more of the form in the view (you did not even show us the input that cannot be bound on submit). To your EDIT.. either you are sending 'null' model or property CompTaskModel of your model class is null

Answer (score 0):

My guess is what is happening is the model binder is having an issue with binding the value to a decimal. I've encountered this before.

Take a look at this: [Model Binding Decimal Values](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx)

See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the code, you are not assigning the value to `TaskValue`, only you are assigning the value to `$("#CompTaskModel_TaskValue").val(v)`.

Also, the error can be when you create the tag `input` to `TaskValue`, maybe you just you're assigning the attribute `id` without the `name` attribute.

Correct example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="TaskValue" id="TaskValue" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Fire change event of this input field after you set  its value.

```
$("yourInputSelector").hide();
$("yourInputSelector").val("your Value");
$("yourInputSelector").trigger("change");
```